# How to do ElevatedButton disabled?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-textinputfield

I want the button to be inactive until 10 characters are entered in the field. When 10 characters were entered, the button was active. And when it is inactive it is gray, and when it is active it is blue. How can I do that?
Here is the input code with the button:

```dart
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                  20, MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0, 20, 0),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  TextField(
                    onChanged: (String value) {
                      setState(() {
                        _showIcon = value.isNotEmpty;
                      });
                    },
                    controller: _inputController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 2.0),
                      ),
                      hintText: "(1201) 565-0123 ",
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 15),
                      helperText: 'Enter your phone number',
                      helperStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 15),
                      suffixIcon: _showIcon
                          ? IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            _inputController.clear();
                            _showIcon = false;
                          });
                        },
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.close, color: Colors.grey),
                      ) : null,
                    ),
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    inputFormatters: [maskFormatter],
                  ),
                 Row(
                   mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                   children: [
                     ElevatedButton(
                         onPressed: () {
                           
                         },
                         child: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_rounded, size: 25),
                       style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                           shape: CircleBorder(),
                           padding: EdgeInsets.all(15)
                       )
                     ),
                   ],
                 )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can call `setState(() {});` on `onChanged` to update the UI, or add listener on `_inputController`.

```dart
ElevatedButton(
    onPressed:
        _inputController.text.length < 10 ? null : () {},
...
```

Passing `onPressed:null` will provide disable state.

Updating UI can be done

```dart
TextField(
  onChanged: (String value) {
    setState(() {});
  },
....)
```

Or

```dart
late final TextEditingController _inputController;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _inputController = TextEditingController()
    ..addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
}
```

Comment: What should I write in setState?

Comment: `TextField`'s `onChanged`. the one you are already doing for `_showIcon`

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable like isEnabled and passing null to the onPress function will disable the button.

```dart
bool isEnabled=false;
void callbackfunction(){
   // add your logic here.
}
....
....
 TextField(
                onChanged: (String value) {
                  if (value.length == 10){
                       setState(()=> isEnabled = true;)
                  }
                  else{
                      isEnabled=false;
                  }
                  setState(() {
                    _showIcon = value.isNotEmpty;
                  });
                },
....
  Row(
               mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
               children: [
                 ElevatedButton(
                     onPressed: isEnabled ? callbackfunction : null,
                     child: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_rounded, size: 25),
                   style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                       color: isEnabled ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
                       shape: CircleBorder(),
                       padding: EdgeInsets.all(15)
                   )
                 ),
               ],
             )
            ],
          ),
```

P.S Please check the syntax I have just provided you the concept.

Comment: I need it to work according to the condition that 10 characters are entered and then it becomes active

Comment: @oleg_ I have edited my answer. Do upvote if it helped you.

Comment: Unfortunately your code doesn't work. At first, the button is gray, and when you enter 10 characters, it does not turn blue